# Term for multipanel scatterplots where each row corresponds to a different variable (e.g. R dataframe plots)

Tags: r, data-visualization, terminology, scatterplot

Is there a general term for multipanel scatterplots where each row corresponds to a different variable, as when calling R's plot function with a data frame as the argument? This image provides an example of what I am referring to:

[image: R multipanel scatterplot where each row corresponds to a different variable]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is often called a scatterplot matrix, [see for instance this](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2013/01/scatterplot-matrices/).